# Include files in Sphinx output on any path

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a project that I'm documenting where I've ended up with a structure like

```
docs/
conf.py
development/
    architecture.rst
    uimockups/
        index.html
        static/
            <supporting css and js files>
        mockup1/
            index.html
            ui1.html
            ui2.html
        mockup2/
            index.html
            ui1.html
            ui2.html
```

Where everything under `uimockups` is just a static site.  For organizational reasons I really want to keep the folder structure as is here, and would like to just copy `uimockups` to `build/development/uimockups` directly, that way I could link to it from my `architecture.rst` file.

I've searched around online, but most of what I can find is pertaining to the `_static` folder for customizing CSS and that sort of thing.  All I want is to copy this entire folder to its corresponding location in the HTML build output.  Is this possible without writing a custom extension?  Can sphinx perform this simple task through configuration alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out *a* solution, but it isn't what I'd consider the *best* solution.

Since I wanted to be able to also do `python -m http.server` in the `docs/development/uimockups` folder and have it work, I ended up:

1. Renaming `docs/development/uimockups/static` to `docs/development/uimockups/_static`.
2. Changing all `.html` files to refer to files in `./_static` or `../_static` as appropriate instead of using an absolute `/static` path.
3. Adding `'development/uimockups'` to the `html_static_path` variable in `conf.py`

This last step is the equivalent of adding `cp development/uimockups/* $BUILD/_static/`, so while not really ideal I end up with

```
$BUILD/
    _static/
        _static/     # From uimockups/
            <supporting files>
        index.html   # From uimockups/
        mockup1/
            ui1.html
            ui2.html
        mockup2/
            ui1.html
            ui2.html
```

Then I can link to this with `` `link text </_static/index.html>`_ `` in my rst files.

I don't really like that I just have to shove this into the `$BUILD/_static` folder, and I can't just have it appear in `$BUILD/development/uimockups` instead, but this doesn't require me to write any code at least.  It's definitely not scaleable though, if I had multiple "static sub-sites" then they would potentially step on each other's resources.  One way to work around this would be to have

```
docs/
    development/
        uimockups-site/
            uimockups/
                index.html
                mockup1/
                mockup2/
                _static/
```

And then add `development/uimockups-site` to my `html_static_path` list so that the output is

```
$BUILD/
    _static/
        uimockups/
            index.html
            mockup1/
            mockup2/
            _static/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `uimockups` to [html_extra_path](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_extra_path) in `conf.py`, and link to files in it as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49967691/sphinx-link-to-an-internal-file-declared-as-html-extra-path).