# Sphinx: link to an internal file declared as html_extra_path

Tags: python, javadoc, python-sphinx

I am currently building a documentation for an API. I am using both Sphinx documentation and Javadoc for that purpose : Javadoc to display the data model, explain the classes serialized, Sphinx to explain routes and general concepts.

I've added my javadoc to a /javadoc subfolder in my sphinx project and declared it as "html_extra_path" in my conf.py. Currently after build, I can see in my /build folder the /javadoc folder, navigate through it.

In my sphinx documentation, I would like to create a link to a page of my javadoc (direct link to the class documentation).

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [external link](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#external-links) without the protocol and hostname.  This reStructuredText:

```
`Javadoc </javadoc>`_
```

...yields the HTML:

```
<a class="reference external" href="/javadoc">Javadoc</a>
```

Comment: Worked ! Thank you !